# AppsScript code show execution completed, but nothing happens to my google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to import a csv attachment from my email to a google sheet. I found a script online that seemed like what I needed and when I click 'run' it shows execution completed, but my google sheet is still blank.

I would prefer the code was able to append the data, but if not that's okay as well.

Here's the script I currently have and links to the [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KqzvyCP1DZjrl3MaxTf8dfoE8LCSUuzv4j-oKOj7kbw/edit?usp=sharing) with current data, [email example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Zgp.jpg), [report example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSeB4.jpg)

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:MY EMAIL");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0];
  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  if (attachment.getContentType() === "CSV") {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
    sheet.clearContents().clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
  }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  Please note if we can reproduce the problem them we may not be able to help you.

Comment: We can't help you extract attachments that we can't view and we can't view stuff that's locked in your gmails

Comment: It looks like you copied this from somewhere else. If you're using someone else's work without giving them credit, that constitutes plagiarism, which is not welcome on Stack Exchange. To fix it, you can [edit], include a [link](/editing-help#links) to the source, mention the author's name, and [quote](/editing-help#simple-blockquotes) the copied content. For more details, see [referencing help](/help/referencing) and [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077/343832).

Comment: Are you sure it's a csv? And why did you change `csv` to `CSV`?

Answer (score 0):

#### Import attachment to google sheet

I have only one message that has an attachment

```
function myfunk() {
  let ts = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  ts.forEach(t => {
    let msgs = t.getMessages();
    msgs.forEach(m => {
      if(m.getAttachments().length > 0) {
        let csv = m.getAttachments()[0].getDataAsString();
        const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
        const vs = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
        sh.getRange(1,1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
      }
    }) 
  })
}
```

The original file:

```
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5,COL6,COL7,COL8,COL9,COL10
1,23,31,14,24,27,12,9,33,18
7,19,23,20,16,33,25,18,12,21
16,11,19,35,14,30,4,14,31,15
33,25,9,29,23,1,26,34,1,14
32,19,20,6,34,20,12,3,7,15
29,31,12,33,33,24,36,20,35,23
13,2,9,39,6,23,5,37,30,38
36,5,10,1,32,24,19,6,28,12
38,39,6,15,30,4,3,13,26,37
```

Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 31 | 14 | 24 | 27 | 12 | 9 | 33 | 18 |
| 7 | 19 | 23 | 20 | 16 | 33 | 25 | 18 | 12 | 21 |
| 16 | 11 | 19 | 35 | 14 | 30 | 4 | 14 | 31 | 15 |
| 33 | 25 | 9 | 29 | 23 | 1 | 26 | 34 | 1 | 14 |
| 32 | 19 | 20 | 6 | 34 | 20 | 12 | 3 | 7 | 15 |
| 29 | 31 | 12 | 33 | 33 | 24 | 36 | 20 | 35 | 23 |
| 13 | 2 | 9 | 39 | 6 | 23 | 5 | 37 | 30 | 38 |
| 36 | 5 | 10 | 1 | 32 | 24 | 19 | 6 | 28 | 12 |
| 38 | 39 | 6 | 15 | 30 | 4 | 3 | 13 | 26 | 37 |